Why are bip32_derivs included in psbt outputs?
I do not want to share my output bip32_derivs as it seems to leak unnecessary info to other participants in collaborative transactions.
Why are bip32_derivs included in psbt outputs?
EDIT: I should have mentioned that I expected walletprocesspsbt to remove all bip32_derivs when setting bip32derivs to false. I wonder if this is a bug or intentional behavior?

The BIP32 derivation field in PSBT outputs is useful to be able to re-derive the address used in the corresponding transaction output. For instance it is useful for a signing device to verify the change address.
